# Mysql Column cannot be null error when there is no result using LEFT JOIN

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery, left-join

I have some data in customer table and there is no data in the other tables. So when I am trying to select using the following query, it gives me

> ## 1048-Column 'customerid' cannot be null

. What could be the problem. Is there a solution for this?

```
SELECT c.*, fd.ruakzat as ruak,
        fd.khatzat as khat, 0+0 as belh, 0+0 as neih, 
        puk.lended as hawh
        FROM `customer` c
        LEFT JOIN ( 
                SELECT s.customerid, o.orderzat as ruakzat, 
                       f.filled as khatzat     
                FROM `sale` s    
                LEFT JOIN (     
                       SELECT SUM(quantity) as orderzat,invoiceno     
                       FROM `order`    
                       WHERE fillstatus='Empty'
                       GROUP BY invoiceno    
                 ) AS o ON s.invoiceno=o.invoiceno    
                LEFT JOIN (     
                      SELECT SUM(quantity) as filled,invoiceno    
                      FROM `order`    
                      WHERE fillstatus='Filled'    
                      GROUP BY invoiceno    
                ) AS f ON s.invoiceno=f.invoiceno    
        ) AS fd ON c.id=fd.customerid    
        LEFT JOIN (     
             SELECT SUM(quantity) as lended, customerid    
             FROM `lending`    
        ) AS puk ON c.id=puk.customerid     
       WHERE (puk.customerid IS NULL OR c.name LIKE '%%')
```

What would be the better approach? Thanks for your help.

Comment: look at `c.id=fd.customerid`. You said there is no customerid in other tables. looks like fd.customerid is coming from `sale` table.

Comment: Yes, you are right. But there is no data in that table. But customerid field is there.

Comment: Are you trying `INSERT INTO ... SELECT`?

Comment: There are 5 `customerid` which one give you the error? Divide and conquer. Test each subquery alone and build your query step by step.

Comment: As @Philipp say, there is nothing in that query to produce that error. You probably are missing something else.

Comment: @Phillip, as you can see from the question, I am querying the customer table with left joining the other three tables. I am not doing insert.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MySQL has a few bug reports around similar issues (https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=31450 , https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=35633 , https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=52441), so it is possible that you encountered the same bug.

To sum it up: if the field in question is non-nullable by definition (defined as not null in the create table), but appears in a subquery where the output result may be null.

Pls check your MySQL version because it may be such a version where one of the above listed bugs do appear.

Furthermore, to me the subquery

```
         SELECT SUM(quantity) as lended, customerid    
         FROM `lending`
```

does not make too much sense, since there is no group by part. This will collapse the lending table into a single record, with customerid randomly chosen from one of the records. So, I would add a `group by customerid` to the above subquery.

Comment: thanks for the answer. I also just found that the problem is from the lending table. I added the group BY and it works. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Not related to your problem, but you can replace those two join

```
        LEFT JOIN (     
               SELECT SUM(quantity) as orderzat,invoiceno     
               FROM `order`    
               WHERE fillstatus='Empty'
               GROUP BY invoiceno    
         ) AS o ON s.invoiceno=o.invoiceno    
        LEFT JOIN (     
              SELECT SUM(quantity) as filled,invoiceno    
              FROM `order`    
              WHERE fillstatus='Filled'    
              GROUP BY invoiceno
```

with a single one using `Conditional SUM`

```
        LEFT JOIN (     
               SELECT invoiceno, 
                      SUM(CASE WHEN fillstatus='Empty' THEN quantity
                                                       ELSE 0
                          END) as orderzat,     
                      SUM(CASE WHEN fillstatus='Filled' THEN quantity
                                                        ELSE 0
                          END) as filled     
               FROM `order`    
               GROUP BY invoiceno    
         ) AS o ON s.invoiceno=o.invoiceno
```